# Pulling data with a class/Tag Name and limiting results

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, automation

I'm trying to web scrape the following website: https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.047.293#ScientificProperties

So far I have the following code that returns the inner text for each `h4` tag.

```
Sub getContents()
        
            Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
            Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            
            Dim SubTag As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
            Dim SubName As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
            
            XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.047.293", False
            XMLReq.send
            
            If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
            
                MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
            
            Set SubTag = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("dt")
            
            For Each SubName In SubTag
            Debug.Print SubName.innerText
            Next SubName
            
        End Sub
```

Although this returns a lot of useful information this also returns a elements with Tag Name `dt` Some results are not wanted (highlighted) but I am unsure how to limit this list. Exploring the HTML there doesnt appear to be any tag/id to distinguish these. This also makes me wonder if I am extracting the information in the best way?
[image]

Similarly if for each of the non highlighted Items in the list I wish to capture the values associated with them on the page e.g.

```
C Physical state at 20°C and 1013 hPa Solid (100%) [1]
C Form Crystalline (100%) [1]
C Odour Other (100%) [1]
C Substance type Organic (100%) [1]
    
    And so on...
```

The tag name for this information is "dd" however I am unsure how I can return both results at the same time. I'm hoping that in the immediate window I can have the list of physical and chemical properties and to the right for each the value is also returned.

Attempting this I have the following code that causes a mismatch error but I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

```
Sub getContents()
        
            Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
            Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
            
            Dim SubTag As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
            Dim SubName As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
            Dim SubInfo As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
            
            XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.047.293", False
            XMLReq.send
            
            If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
            
                MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
                Exit Sub
            End If
            
            HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
            
            Set SubTag = HTMLDoc.getElementsByTagName("dt")
            Set SubInfo = SubTag.tags("dd")
            
            For Each SubName In SubTag
            Debug.Print SubName.innerText, SubInfo.innerText
            Next SubName
            
        End Sub
```

I appreciate its a long post but if anyone could comment on what I am doing wrong that would be great.

UPDATE:

The following code better achieves the desired data in the immediate windows.

```
Sub GetContents()
    
        Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        
        Dim SubSectList As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
        Dim SubSects As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
        Dim SubSect As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
    
        XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.047.293", False
        XMLReq.send
        
        If XMLReq.Status <> 200 Then
        
            MsgBox "Problem" & vbNewLine & XMLReq.Status & " - " & XMLReq.statusText
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText
        
        Set SubSectList = HTMLDoc.getElementsByClassName("col-xs-12 col-lg-10 MainContent")(1)
        Set SubSects = SubSectList.getElementsByTagName("dt")

        'Debug.Print SubSects.Length
        
        For Each SubSect In SubSects
        Debug.Print SubSect.innerText & " : "; SubSect.NextSibling.innerText
       Next SubSect
 
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to restrict to those dt that are children of elements with class EndpointContent; then you can chain nextSibling to move to adjacent dd

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetContents()
    Dim XMLReq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim HTMLDoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
        
    XMLReq.Open "Get", "https://echa.europa.eu/brief-profile/-/briefprofile/100.047.293", False
    XMLReq.send
                  
    HTMLDoc.body.innerHTML = XMLReq.responseText

    Dim i As Long
    
    With HTMLDoc.querySelectorAll(".EndpointContent dt")
        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
            Debug.Print .Item(i).innerText & " : " & .Item(i).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText
            Debug.Print
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I seem to be getting a runtime error `91`: Object variable or with block variable not set, when I run this code. the Error appears to lie with the line `Debug.Print .Item(i).innerText & " : " & .Item(i).NextSibling.NextSibling.innerText` Any thoughts?

Comment: I will need to test this evening. Ran ok yesterday.

Comment: @Nick I checked QHarrs code and it works like it is, for me. It reads the values which are in the tab "Scientific properties" on the website if you use a webbrowser. I use Excel 2016 32 Bit on Windows 10 64 Bit Current version

Comment: @Zwenn Hi both, I've just given it another go and yes it does work. Now I need to explore pulling both the sub name as well as the data but this is a good step forward so thank you!

Comment: @QHarr Not sure why however the error that initially appeared has returned. It seems to occur after running the code a few times.

Comment: I have provided an update to my code by taking the NextSibling aspect of your code. This  seems to work well. If anyone knows how I can limit this list for given physical or chemical properties that would be a bonus although now necessary.

Comment: 1) the data hasn't returned - server/connection timing 2) blocking. Most likely 1. You would then implement a retry strategy.

Comment: Ah Yeah I think that explains another issue Im having. Thank you!